# Removing hyperlinks on white-spaces

Tags: html, css

Problem: The white-spaces on the left and right of the image are hyperlinks. I want the images to be displayed as a list- all center aligned horizontally.

The white-spaces should be there but they shouldn't be hyperlinks. The whole page is a hyperlink right now.

Sorry guys I'm new to html/css. So this might be something basic that I might be missing. I managed to place the images in the center but I am stuck with white-space hyperlinks right now.

```
<a href="http://cashkaro.com/stores/overcart"  target="_blank"><img height=100 width=340 style="   display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/cashKaro2_1.jpg"}}" alt="Overcart coupons at CashKaro" /></a>

<a href="http://www.couponzguru.com/overcart-coupons/" target="_blank"><img height=100 width=340 style="   display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/couponzGuru.jpg"}}" alt="Overcart coupons at Couponzguru"/></a>

<a href="http://www.couponmama.co.in/stores/overcart/" target="_blank"><img height=100 width=340 style="   display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/couponMama.png"}}" alt="Overcart coupons at couponmama"/></a>

<a href="http://www.couponrani.com/overcart-coupons" target="_blank"><img height=100 width=340 style="   display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/couponRani_copy.png"}}" alt="Overcart coupons at couponrani"/></a>

<a href="https://www.maddycoupons.in/stores/overcart-coupons/" target="_blank"><img height=100 width=340 style="   display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/maddyCoupons.png"}}" alt="Overcart coupons at maddycoupons"/></a>

<a href="http://www.coupondunia.in/overcart" target="_blank"><img height=100 width=340 style="   display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/CouponDunia.jpg"}}" alt="Overcart coupons at coupondunia"/></a>
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't trouble yourself with inline style defining. 
use elements to define the order. and add this style.

```
p
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

here is the fiddle solution. have a look at it. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hd9a430y/)

Comment: Thanks. Your fiddle solution is perfect. Just what I wanted. Simple and smart.

Comment: happy to help. keep helping others too. thanks for the upvote

Answer (score 0):

Well to start you need to fix your HTML.

```
height="100" width="340"
```

Also you can't do

```
display: inlined;
```

it should be:

```
display: inline;
```

Otherwise I don't know what you mean by whitespace? You probably don't need most of the inline CSS you've written either.

Comment: I made the corrections - removed px from 100px and changed inline to block.

Comment: What I meant is, the images should be displayed as they currently are i.e. centered horizontally, one bellow the other. But the white-space on left and right of every image is a hyperlink (like an extension of the image). I don't want to remove the white-space but they shouldn't be hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure what you exactly wanted, so I made two solutions.

[All in a column in the middle of the page](http://pastebin.com/EFTQy4iw)
[All side-by-side](http://pastebin.com/8bRp5qwC)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem was "White spaces acting as hyperlinks although it is not.".

If you could use JavaScript, try delete <a> and add this attribute to your <img>:

```
onclick="window.location.href='http://www.example.com/';"
```

But, if you couldn't use JavaScript use this:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">
 <img style="width: 45%; height: 100px; display: inline; margin-left: 27%;" src="..." alt="..."/>
</a>
```

"display: block;" will take up the whole line. So, use "display: inline;" instead.